# Why is mail going to an old mailserver after I changed the MX records?

Tags: email, mx-record

I have a strange problem. I had to transfer mails from one server to another. I set up a server with QMail and Plesk, and everything is working. I created mail accounts similar to the accounts on the old server. I exported all mails and contacts from the old server to the new. I changed the DNS MX record to point to the new server.

For some unknown reason, some mails are still going to the old server and some are coming to the new server. I have waited for about four days before posting this, and the problem still persists. On Saturday I changed the A record too, but this did not solve the problem with mails. The website itself is working fine.

Here are the full headers of a message received by the old server:

```
Return-Path: <stvcentral.53802@envfrm.rsys5.com>
Delivered-To: addr of email
Received: from smtp54.gate.dfw1a (smtp54.gate.dfw1a.rsapps.net [172.20.100.54]) by store28a.mail.dfw1a (SMTP Server) with ESMTP id AE7851800C3 for <addr of email>; Mon, 28 Jul 2014 03:18:03 -0400 (EDT)
X-Virus-Scanned: OK
X-MessageSniffer-Scan-Result: 0
X-MessageSniffer-Rules: 0-0-0-32767-c
X-CMAE-Scan-Result: 0
X-CNFS-Analysis: v=2.1 cv=De0u9JdW c=1 sm=0 tr=0 a=aV+O4xzSBt0o+0xwPG4XAQ==:117 a=YHITJaTJE1uX1sExSpua6g==:17 a=kPqwDtNfjqQA:10 a=nzGiYrXWIbwA:10 a=IkcTkHD0fZMA:10 a=21-350hwAAAA:8 a=EAyIgLxwAAAA:8 a=KGjhK52YXX0A:10 a=SSmOFEACAAAA:8 a=g49rjhyEAAAA:8 a=4F_gcz9cAAAA:8 a=zbF6CNjXAAAA:8 a=tCyDjBcLanOAYrL7iOwA:9 a=XAZpLiLyquuSxLXB:21 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=frz4AuCg-hUA:10 a=tXsnliwV7b4A:10 a=p403mkujtbAA:10
Received: from [173.203.2.22] ([173.203.2.22:34803] helo=smtp50.gate.ord1a) by smtp54.gate.dfw1a.rsapps.net (envelope-from <stvcentral.53802@envfrm.rsys5.com>) (ecelerity 2.2.3.49 r(42060/42061)) with ESMTPS (cipher=AES256-SHA) id 38/97-15214-B29F5D35; Mon, 28 Jul 2014 03:18:03 -0400
X-Virus-Scanned: OK
X-Spam-Threshold: 95
X-Spam-Score: 0
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Virus-Scanned: OK
X-MessageSniffer-Scan-Result: 0
X-MessageSniffer-Rules: 0-0-0-32767-c
X-CMAE-Scan-Result: 0
X-CNFS-Analysis: v=2.1 cv=CaAxutbl c=1 sm=0 tr=0 b=1 a=YHITJaTJE1uX1sExSpua6g==:117 a=YHITJaTJE1uX1sExSpua6g==:17 a=kPqwDtNfjqQA:10 a=IkcTkHD0fZMA:10 a=EAyIgLxwAAAA:8 a=SSmOFEACAAAA:8 a=g49rjhyEAAAA:8 a=4F_gcz9cAAAA:8 a=zbF6CNjXAAAA:8 a=tCyDjBcLanOAYrL7iOwA:9 a=Yqh-dnuOVIS8Y9aZ:21 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=frz4AuCg-hUA:10 a=tXsnliwV7b4A:10 a=p403mkujtbAA:10
X-Orig-To: addr of email
X-Originating-Ip: [199.7.206.83]
Received: from [199.7.206.83] ([199.7.206.83:37806] helo=omp.watch.stv.tv) by smtp50.gate.ord1a.rsapps.net (envelope-from <stvcentral.53802@envfrm.rsys5.com>) (ecelerity 2.2.3.49 r(42060/42061)) with ESMTP id 8E/D5-07869-A29F5D35; Mon, 28 Jul 2014 03:18:02 -0400
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=stv; d=watch.stv.tv; h=MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:Message-ID; i=stv@watch.stv.tv; bh=mxqrrGTiasxtjXc9p4MuF7H9E6k=; b=KI6T+Ly8U+/UemVHnzRvwTVkcRjAPw8w8cMhRuszpwnUs/jc81uT1TN6bMdlX0L9+dJHQrhyQBIk EpGoFi+nCKG/wq2cRCJ7ysyvL5o2UPY4NLoN/Y7kC8al5C7FrqK5KJypVwiJ4pb8EijkZQJdwMcS gBu6FWUQtKQkVPu73+4=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=stv; d=watch.stv.tv; b=LkN79EBZBlw7afoQitGZyQhGfT3p5yAqMX5Z/01WfBA9QUBLyKGAJhHLe6tuDtxHMn+rwmeIqMbA ZYrqe09+WFTSGNXMWvtK3nad8bn/G/a78FqDdKLr4gl6lWrVXXZFudNZgc2H9MMcrGo8vzCdh9xw ory1zjVuHdoXsgg0wBs=;
Received: by omp.watch.stv.tv id hqnsik1607gm for <addr of email>; Mon, 28 Jul 2014 00:17:55 -0700 (envelope-from <stvcentral.53802@envfrm.rsys5.com>)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Date: Mon, 28 Jul 2014 00:17:55 -0700
To: addr of email
From: "STV" <stv@watch.stv.tv>
Reply-To: "STV" <reply@watch.stv.tv>
Subject: Murder enquiry launched, Scotland's youngest ever Games medallist and could you spot a lie?!
List-Unsubscribe: <https://watch.stv.tv/pub/optout/UnsubscribeOneStepConfirmAction?YES=true&_ri_=X0Gzc2X%3DWQpglLjHJlYQGoU2TNepP6Hzc7zaIzfNzeLmzdLzatpzeUEaPivC2k&_ei_=EolaGGF4SNMvxFF7KucKuWPFoKkKtpKpImTodsIb_k1PEsdOhTq-gg>, <mailto:unsubscribe-WQpglLjHJlYQGoU2TNepP6Hzc7zaIzfNzeLmzdLzatpzeUEaPivC2k@imh.rsys5.com?subject=List-Unsubscribe>
X-sgxh1: iHmtxJoHItHpkqnjhmiQJhu
X-rext: 4.interact5.Eh3T2vLiyAaXBQbxvVeuZeQliV3GHypN8Ts
X-cid: stvcentral.254285
Message-ID: <0.0.2D.272.1CFAA340D52434E.0@omp.watch.stv.tv>
```

And here are the full headers of a message received by the new server:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on myhosting.pl
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-0.7 required=5.0 tests=FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW autolearn=ham version=3.3.1
received: (qmail 759 invoked from network); 25 Jul 2014 08:44:46 +0100
received: from smtp2a.hushmail.com (HELO smtp2.hushmail.com) (65.39.178.237) by ip-10-84-13-195.eu-west-1.compute.internal with (DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 encrypted) SMTP; 25 Jul 2014 08:44:46 +0100
received: from smtp2.hushmail.com (smtp2a.hushmail.com [65.39.178.237])by smtp2.hushmail.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 5F06EA00F4for <addr mail on my new server>; Fri, 25 Jul 2014 07:44:43 +0000 (UTC)
received: from smtp.hushmail.com (w8.hushmail.com [65.39.178.52])by smtp2.hushmail.com (Postfix) with ESMTPfor <addr mail on my new server>; Fri, 25 Jul 2014 07:44:41 +0000 (UTC)
received: by smtp.hushmail.com (Postfix, from userid 99)id 4118860937; Fri, 25 Jul 2014 07:44:41 +0000 (UTC)
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Fri, 25 Jul 2014 09:44:41 +0200
To: mail on my new server
Subject: Re: sadsdsa
From: forek92@hush.ai
In-Reply-To: <9064866e6f8776c562917b1629608d1a@my-domain>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary="=_02be226817c36e7068ee7874b3a62770"
Message-Id: <20140725074441.4118860937@smtp.hushmail.com>
```

Comment: What was the TTL of the MX record when you made the change?

Comment: As a part of this move, have you changed the DNS servers also? Or are you still using the same DNS server as before?

Comment: I setup my own DNS server with Plesk and repoint domain to this DNS server. I change in Plesk A record to IP connected to old server to have time for transfer mails. Now I have all records pointed to my IP.  @TeroKilkanen TTL.. I don't know. For my DNS server the TTL is one day.

Comment: Can you please post the headers for an e-mail appearing in the old server, as well as the headers for an e-mail appearing in the new server?

Comment: Yes, of course. Sory for cutting email address. This is from old server: http://pastebin.com/KfkgdiPk and from new server: http://pastebin.com/Aq7LuatM

Comment: Also, when I check my DNS with dnscheck.pingdom.com I have problem Too few IPv4 name servers (1).

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into the question itself, rather than leaving them buried in comments.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options This appears to me to be either a case of DNS caching or of DNS poisoning

I'm guessing the old DNS server has very long timeouts (like a week) and/or is acting as an authoriative server and serving up the old records to whoever asks it.  If it happens to be a large ISP who does not run separate caching and authoritative servers, the old DNS server will continue to answer incorrectly until the zone is removed.   (I've seen this problem with one of New Zealands largest ISPs, so its not uncommon).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response. How to check that this is a DNS poisoning? Or if this is caching, can I solve this problem? The old server will be down on 1st August

Comment: If the problem is caching there is (practically) nothing you can do about it - it will fix itself once the cache expires.   It would be surprising if caching is longer then a week.  If its DNS poisoning you would need to find the nameservers being used (ie the old nameservers) and direct a query at them to see the response.  In Linux you can do this with the command dig @XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX domain.name MX  (where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is their nameserver IP, and the request checks the MX record). ...cont

Comment: It looks like you can download something similar for Windows - see http://www.danesparza.net/2011/05/using-the-dig-dns-tool-on-windows-7/   - Ideally you will want to do this from a connection that the ISP uses - as they may refuse connections from elsewhere - although in theory this should not matter if they are answering authoratively.   Also, you will want to check ALL their nameservers.    Note that if you do a dig @XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX domain.name soa  the number which appears to the right of the domain name in the answer is the number of seconds before the domain name cache will timeout.

Comment: dig mydomain return valid IP. This is a result from dig for old server: http://pastebin.com/dT5jxSni and for new server: http://pastebin.com/nvhrMRxK